# sql string can't get right

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get some data from my db.

It kinda looks like this

GROUPS

`groups_id`, `groups_name`, `groups_description`, `groups_active`, `groups_hash`, `groups_entry_date`, `user_id`, `groups_email`, `groups_sms`

CUSTOMERS_GROUPS

`customers_hash`, `groups_hash`

CUSTOMERS

`customers_id`, `customers_first_name`, `customers_surname`, `customers_telephone`, `customers_email`, `customers_telephone_active`, `customers_email_active`, `client_type`, `customers_hash`, `customers_entry_date`

I want customers.groups_hash and groups.groups_name in a concat form. Here is my attempt ...

```
SELECT * , GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT customers_groups.groups_hash
SEPARATOR '/' ) , GROUP_CONCAT( groups.groups_name
SEPARATOR '/' )
FROM customers
INNER JOIN customers_groups ON ( customers.customers_hash = customers_groups.customers_hash )
LEFT JOIN groups ON ( customers_groups.customers_hash = groups.groups_hash )
WHERE groups.groups_active ='1' GROUP BY customers.customers_entry_date
```

but it gives me back a zero set ...

Comment: Well, the WHERE clause and INNER JOIN typically impact the amount of rows returned. What happens when you take off the WHERE or change the INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I don't understand your bridge table. Why does it link `customers_hash` with `groups_hash`? I would rather expect `customers_id` with `groups_id`. What are these hashes for? What do they actually represent? And you want one result row per `customers_entry_date`? Then `select *, ...` makes no sense; it should be `select customers_entry_date, ...`. At last, why the left outer join? Can there possibly exist a `customers_groups` record without a matching record in `groups`?

Comment: One more thing: `groups.groups_active` is a string? Why? I'd rather expect a boolean. Or is this not about yes/no, but about levels of activeness? In that case: what else beside numbers does it contain? Wouldn't a numeric column suffice, so you'd compare with the number `1` and not with the string `'1'`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your where clause. It must be part of the on clause:

```
SELECT * , GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT customers_groups.groups_hash
SEPARATOR '/' ) , GROUP_CONCAT( groups.groups_name
SEPARATOR '/' )
FROM customers
INNER JOIN customers_groups ON ( customers.customers_hash = customers_groups.customers_hash )
LEFT JOIN groups ON ( customers_groups.customers_hash = groups.groups_hash ) AND groups.groups_active ='1' 
GROUP BY customers.customers_entry_date
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
LEFT JOIN groups ON ( customers_groups.customers_hash = groups.groups_hash )
```

which should probably be

```
LEFT JOIN groups ON ( customers_groups.groups_hash = groups.groups_hash )
```

(While it remains unclear what the hashes actually represent and why there is no bridge table linking the tables' IDs instead. I've asked that question in the comment section to your request.)